# What information can I get from a socket connected to a server using c++ and windows?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking

I have a server and when a client connects to the server, I want to take all the information from the client and make a struct with it.
What information can I get?
I know that I can get the ipv4 and port from the client, there is anything left that I can get?

This is a short way of doing it:

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT 32406

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    hint.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET listeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(listeningSocket, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
    listen(listeningSocket, SOMAXCONN);

    sockaddr_in socketInfo;
    int socketInfoLen = sizeof(socketInfo);
    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listeningSocket, (sockaddr*)&socketInfo, &socketInfoLen);

    std::cout << inet_ntoa(socketInfo.sin_addr) << std::endl;
    std::cout << socketInfo.sin_port << std::endl;

    shutdown(clientSocket, SD_BOTH);
    closesocket(clientSocket);
    closesocket(listeningSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sockets and networking are not part of C++ (ISO 14882).  They are facilities provided by something else, like Boost ASIO or the operating system.  You'll need to refer to the document of the facilities you are using for your platform.

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: I am not home right now, sorry, when I get home I will post some code.

Comment: I am using windows sockets api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a whole lot of information available from `getsockopt`.  It is a superset of what the other answer claims, for example

> `SO_BSP_STATE` Returns the local address, local port, remote address, remote port, socket type, and protocol used by a socket.

Since you have a TCP socket you will be particularly interested in

- [IPPROTO_TCP socket options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/ipproto-tcp-socket-options)

There is different information available through `WSAIoctl`, for example

- [TCP_INFO_v1 structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mstcpip/ns-mstcpip-tcp_info_v1)

Some of these details will be local socket options (such as blocking or non-blocking), others will relate to the connection itself (e.g. negotiated window size).  Some information about the remote client will be revealed, although not as much as if you used a bespoke fingerprinting tool.

Comment: can you show me how to use getsockopt with the SO_BSP_STATE flag? I cant find anything useful on the internet or idk what to look for. Thanks!

Comment: @ClaudiuHBann: [The official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/so-bsp-state) looks pretty useful.  If after reading that you still can't get it to work, it may be worth a new specialized question.  But that particular information is easier to get [via `getsockname()` and `getpeername()` as Remy commented already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722611/what-information-can-i-get-from-a-socket-connected-to-a-server-using-c-and-win/67726166?noredirect=1#comment119709149_67724165)

Comment: seems like I don't know how to read :))
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation of **@Ben Voigt**'s answer, if someone needs it:

```c
#include <WinSock2.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

bool GetSocketState(SOCKET sock, CSADDR_INFO& state) {
    union CSADDR_INFO_PADDED {
        CSADDR_INFO csaddr;
        TCHAR padding[128];
    } csaddrPadded {};

    int infoLen = sizeof(csaddrPadded);
    if (getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BSP_STATE, (TCHAR*)&csaddrPadded, &infoLen)) {
        return false;
    }

    state = csaddrPadded.csaddr;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only information you get that the client doesn't explicitly send is the [`sockaddr_in`](https://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/sockaddr_inman.html) structure, ie the port and source IP address. Though of course you only get this when the client initiates a transfer (sends a packet with UDP or connects with TCP).

To get anything else, the client needs to send it as part of regular communication.

Comment: "*The only information you get ... is ... the port and source IP address*" - That is not entirely true. In TCP, you can also get the destination IP address and port that the client connected to. Since the server is binding to `INADDR_ANY`, the client can `connect()` to any IP that belongs to the server. `accept()` and `getpeername()` will tell you where the client is coming from, while `getsockname()` will tell you where the client is actually connected to.  In UDP, there is also `WSARecvMsg()` which can tell you which IP a packet was sent to and which network interface actually received it.

Comment: In case of a TCP socket (which this is) it should also be possible (although it may be tricky) to get information about the negotiated TCP options which are in the TCP header, such as window size, etc.

Comment: I thought it obvious he wanted information about the client, not the server